# How to generate a negative binomial distribution with different sample sizes for power analyses in R?

Tags: r, simulation, distribution, power-analysis

I try to do a power simulation with an outcome variable that is zero-inflated. So I use a negative binomial distribution. What I need is the following distribution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
rt_random <- 
rnbinom(n = 2000, mu = 25, size = .9) 
qplot(rt_random)
```

[image: desired distribution]

Now, I tried to create a function where I can use different sample sizes for the power simulation. I use the `pmap`function for this. However this does not seem to work. The final distribution is not zero-inflated at all and the mean is not close to the defined mean:

```r
generate_distribution <- function(n, mus, sizes){
  tibble(n = n, 
       t_mu = mus, 
       t_size = sizes)%>% 
  mutate(rt = pmap(list(n, t_mu, t_size),
                     ~rnbinom(..1, ..2, ..3))) %>% 
  unnest(rt) 
  
}
set.seed(123)
rt_df <- 
  generate_distribution(n = 2000,
                        mus = 25,
                        sizes = .9)
qplot(rt_df$rt)
```

[image: wrong distribution]

Is there an easy way to change my code so that I get the desired distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your lambda function, you are not using the argument names for `rnbinom`. The default order for the arguments if you don't name them is `n, size, prob, mu`, so you are passing 2000 to `n`, 25 to `size` and 0.9 to `prob`. Just name the arguments explicitly as you did in your first example, and your code will work.

```r
generate_distribution <- function(n, mus, sizes){
  tibble(n = n, 
       t_mu = mus, 
       t_size = sizes)%>% 
  mutate(rt = pmap(list(n, t_mu, t_size),
                     ~rnbinom(n = ..1, mu = ..2, size = ..3))) %>% 
  unnest(rt) 
}

set.seed(123)
rt_df <- 
  generate_distribution(n = 2000,
                        mus = 25,
                        sizes = .9)
qplot(rt_df$rt)
```

[image]

Comment: And because `summarize` is now more permissive about returning multiple rows, the function can be simplified: `tibble(n = n, 
         t_mu = mus, 
         t_size = sizes)%>% 
    group_by(t_mu) %>% 
    summarize(rt = rnbinom(n = n, mu = t_mu, size = t_size))`